# Why can't the Cora Z7 execute the a.out file? (-sh: ./a.out: No such file or directory)

Tags: petalinux

I have two devices, one is an x86_64 PC(my local computer), and the other one runs Petalinux on a Cora Z7.

```
petalinux_project:~$ uname -a
Linux petalinux_project 5.15.36-xilinx-v2022.2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 3 07:50:07 UTC 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I used the command `$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.c` to build a.out in my local computer, then transferred it to the Cora Z7 using scp. When I try to execute `$./a.out` on the Cora Z7, an error occurs.

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, Cora Z7!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
petalinux_project:~$ ./a.out 
-sh: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

The issue persists even when executing with absolute paths.

```
petalinux_project:~$ pwd
/home/petalinux
petalinux_project:~$ /home/petalinux/a.out 
-sh: /home/petalinux/a.out: No such file or directory
```

I have no clue about this issue. How can I solve it? Thank you.